# PHP: How to retrieve extract text from Wiki API

Tags: php, api, wikipedia-api

I have the following call I do to Wiki to retrieve info about places, which users search for via an input called 'location'

```
// get wiki info about search term
$wiki_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=' . urlencode($_GET['location']);
```

EXAMPLE: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=hungary

```
// get result of Wiki Search
$wiki_json = file_get_contents($wiki_url);


// decode data to use in php
$wiki_array = json_decode($wiki_json, true);
```

I've tried to get the text the same way I've done for other APIs but its not working because it seems I need the pageId to access the array where the text sits.

Is there a way to bypass this and get the text without knowing the pageID?

Comment: Sure, you could extract `pages` and use `reset()` / `current()`, or you could loop around that property with a foreach, You could use `array_values()` on the `pages` property, or use `array_keys` on it to get a list of the page ids etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you explain about extracting pages, I tried $wiki_array['query']['pages']; but I am still stuck.

Comment: To be honest, the `foreach` option is going to be your best bet. `foreach($wiki_array['query']['pages'] as $page)` then `$page` will be the array that you're after. You should then make sure you can deal with multiple results properly.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. Please add as an answer.

Comment: Done. Glad it's worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various possible solutions to this.

You could use [reset()](http://php.net/reset) / [current()](http://php.net/current) against the `pages` property to get the first / current item in that array, or you could loop around that property with a `foreach` and ignore the keys. You could also use [array_values()](http://php.net/array_values) on the `pages` property to get force sequential indicies, or use [array_keys()](http://php.net/array_keys) on it to get a list of the page ids and use those to access each item. (There are other ways).

The `foreach` option is going to be your best bet.

```
foreach($wiki_array['query']['pages'] as $page)
```

$page inside the loop will be the array that you're after.

You should then make sure you can deal with multiple results properly.